# How to do this in ReactJS using functional components?

Tags: reactjs

how to do this using reactjs

this is my html code

```
<style>
    ul li {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 5px 20px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        width: 200px;
    }
    .my-li.active{
        background: rgb(179, 131, 224);
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>

<ul>
<li class="my-li">
    <label for="item1">Item 1</label>
    <input class="my-cbx" type="checkbox" id="item1">
</li>
<li class="my-li">
    <label for="item2">Item 2</label>
    <input class="my-cbx" type="checkbox" id="item2">
</li>
<li class="my-li">
    <label for="item3">Item 3</label>
    <input class="my-cbx" type="checkbox" id="item3">
</li>
<li class="my-li">
    <label for="item4">Item 4</label>
    <input class="my-cbx" type="checkbox" id="item4">
</li>
<li class="my-li">
    <label for="item5">Item 5</label>
    <input class="my-cbx" type="checkbox" id="item5">
</li>
```

```
<script>

const myli = document.querySelectorAll('.my-li')
const mycbx = document.querySelectorAll('.my-cbx')

myli.forEach((li)=>{
    li.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
        let childBX = e.target.children[1]
        if(childBX.checked==true){
            childBX.checked=false
        }else{
            childBX.checked=true
        }
        if(childBX.checked==true){
            e.target.classList.add('active')
        }else{
            e.target.classList.remove('active')
        }
    })
})
```

every time i click li the child checkbox will toggle checked/unchecked and when the checkbox is true/checked the li or parent element of the checkbox will change the background to blue

Comment: You are basically asking how to make a React component here. This isn't really the purpose of Stackoverflow. What have you tried already on your own as a [mcve]?

Comment: no sir, i just want the javascript code to convert in reactjs

Comment: Well, that is what React is, components that combine Javascript and HTML.